# Monkey patching Fixnum and Bignum without duplication

Tags: ruby, monkeypatching

I have added two small helpers for working with numbers but I found that I had to copy paste my method to make it work with both `Bignum` and `Fixnum`. How can I write a method for both the number classes without such copy-paste?

```
class Bignum
    def digits
        self.to_s.split('').map(&:to_i)
    end

    def palindrome?
        self.to_s == self.to_s.reverse
    end
end

class Fixnum
    def digits
        self.to_s.split('').map(&:to_i)
    end

    def palindrome?
        self.to_s == self.to_s.reverse
    end
end
```

Comment: Have fun with Project Euler. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both classes inherit from [`Integer`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Integer.html). Monkeypatch that if you want to affect both. From the docs:

> ### Integer
>
> This class is the basis for the two concrete classes that hold whole numbers, `Bignum` and `Fixnum`.

```
2.0.0-p353 :001 > class Integer; def worked?; true; end; end
#=> nil 
2.0.0-p353 :002 > 42.worked?
#=> true 
2.0.0-p353 :003 > 42.class
#=> Fixnum 
2.0.0-p353 :004 > big = 2**90
#=> 1237940039285380274899124224 
2.0.0-p353 :005 > big.worked?
#=> true 
2.0.0-p353 :006 > big.class
#=> Bignum
```

You can find the common classes and modules of both using set intersection:

```
Fixnum.ancestors & Bignum.ancestors
#=> [Integer, Numeric, Comparable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

---

For the case when two classes (or more) do not share an appropriate common module or class, you can alternatively do either this:

```
module MyExtension
  def palindrome?
    ...
  end
end

class NumbaOne
  include MyExtension
end

class NumbaTwo
  include MyExtension
end
```

Or, if you don't want to modify the entire class, but just certain instances:

```
a1 = NumbaOne.new
a2 = NumbaOne.new
b1 = NumbaTwo.new

[a1,a2,b1].each{ |o| o.extend MyExtension }
```

Comment: What if the most common ancestor is not a class? (ex. `Array.ancestors & Range.ancestors` -> `Enumerable`)

Comment: @Caridorc you can use  `Array.ancestors.grep(Class)` to select classes